# Libraries paths defined by Master bash script, but having to run it in every terminal session, how to make more efficient?

Tags: linux, bash, path, fortran

I have build a set of libraries and many of my Fortran programs will use them. This creates a problem in that if I ever need to change the location of the libraries then I will need to individually update the path directories in each make file.

How is this usually overcome? I have planned instead to have each make file read a path from a single master path file in the home or root directory (this files location will never change). Within this file is the path for each Library and if any path changes only this file needs to updated.

So I wrote a bash script file, called Master_Library_Paths:

```
export Library1_Name = {Library1_Name_Path}
echo $Library1_Name
export Library2_Name = {Library2_Name_Path}
echo $Library2_Name
export Library3_Name = {Library3_Name_Path}
echo $Library3_Name
```

And placed it in my home directory. Then in the make files, I have a line:

```
$(shell . {Path for Master_Library_Paths} ) \
```

And load the libraries:

```
-I$(Library1_Name)
-I$(Library2_Name)
-I$(Library3_Name)
```

This works great if I run ./Master_Library_Paths in the terminal session first and then go to the directory to compile the program, however that is quite time consuming, How can I fix it so that these arguments Library1_Name, Library2_Name ect are known throughout the system?

Comment: You could consider [tag:pkg-config]?

Answer (score 0):

New system wide LD_LIBRARY_PATH´s can be added in /etc/ld.so.conf , /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

Or may be in /etc/profile.d/

-